# Connecting to MySQL via SSH in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I know there's so many questions asked about the same thing but I'm unable to fix my issue.

I have a database that I can only access via PuTTY or MySQL Workbench - it has to be via an SSH connection.  However, I need to be able to use this database connection via PHP and I cannot get it working.

Here's the details for the connection (IPs, Usernames and Passwords are all changed for security):

```
> SSH Host ($ssh_host): 123.45.67.890
> SSH User ($ssh_user): ssh_user
> SSH Pass ($ssh_pass): ssh_pass
> MySQL Host ($mysql_host): 123.12.34.123
> MySQL User ($mysql_user): mysql_user
> MySQL Pass ($mysql_pass): mysql_pass
> MySQL Server Port  ($port): 3306
> Default Schema ($db): default
```

When I use PuTTY, I connect to the SSH Host and then I run the following executions:

```
> (asks for login): ssh_user
> (asks for password): ssh_pass
> mysql -umysql_user -h123.12.34.123 -p;
> (asks for password): mysql_pass
> \u default
> *RUN SQL QUERY HERE LIKE*: DESCRIBE table;
```

When trying to connect to the database within PHP, I'm struggling.

I originally tried using the SSH2 functions within PHP:

```
$ssh_conn = ssh2_connect($ssh_host, $port);
if ($ssh_conn) {
    print "connection successful<br />";
} else {
    print "connection failed<br />";
    die();
}

$ssh_auth = ssh2_auth_password($ssh_conn, $ssh_user, $ssh_pass);
if ($ssh_conn) {
    print "authentication successful<br />";
} else {
    print "authentication failed<br />";
    die();
}

$ssh_tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($ssh_conn, $mysql_host, $port);
if ($ssh_tunnel) {
    print "tunnel successful<br />";
} else {
    print "tunnel failed<br />";
    die();
}

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($ssh_tunnel, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db);
if (!$mysqli) {
    print "errno: ".mysqli_connect_errno()."<br />";
    print "error: ".mysqli_connect_error()."<br />";
    die();
} else {
    print "mysql connection successful<br />";
}
```

Everything works and prints "successful" until I try and use mysqli_connect and then I get the following response:

```
errno: 0
error:
```

The logfile shows:

```
mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given
```

After a bit of googling, I end up finding out that SSH2_TUNNEL doesn't "allow you to specify a local port when opening an SSH tunnel".  Not sure if that's causing the issue in my code, I attempt to move on with other suggestions and found this:
http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html

However, this is where I'm struggling and I don't seem to be getting my head wrapped around what I should be putting in place of the placeholders:

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@remotehost.com
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 ssh_user@ssh_host
```

I've tried changing the localhost IP to be the ssh_host AND mysql_host, just in case, and they didn't work either.

With all the data I've given above, can someone be so obvious with exactly what I need in order to make it work?  Can I do it solely via PHP functions or do I need to run commands?

***EDIT***

As per comments from @LSerni, I've just tried running this (replace $vars with the values from above):

```
exec("ssh -fNg -L 3306:$mysql_host:3306 $ssh_user@$ssh_host");
mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $default);
```

However, the error I'm getting now is (again, replace $var with value above):

```
mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user '$mysql_user'@'localhost'
```

Comment: you ever solve this? There still isn't any good way to use php / ssh and mysql

Answer (score 1):

From the machine where you're running MySQL Workbench, run a SSH session forwarding the MySQL port:

```
ssh -fNg -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@remotehost.com
```

If I have misunderstood and you actually have THREE machines - the one you SSH to, the one you SSH from, and the database server; or if the authentication uses the *external* interface (i.e. the IP you SSH to, and the DB server, are the same) then you need

```
ssh -fNg -L 3306:123.45.67.8:3306 myuser@remotehost.com
```

where 123.45.67.8 is the address of your DB server. This also works if 123.45.67.8 is the machine where both the SSH and MySQL servers are, because you might hit an authentication error otherwise (user@123.45.67.8 and user@127.0.0.1 are two different auths).

Now, from the same machine, you can connect to host 127.0.0.1 (**not** "localhost" as this might be interpreted as a Unix socket), using the username and password that you know are working on the remote machine.

I've tried this just now on my test machine and it works.

Remember to **NOT** use "MySQL client compressed protocol" or you'll experience noticeable delays, as the SSH connection is already compressed.

(Also, some SSH ciphers will yield slightly better performance than others).

Comment: I'm running MySQL Workbench on my local machine but my code is on a remote server.  When I run this code from the remote server, I get the following error:

"errno: 1045
error: Access denied for user 'mysql_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: What are you using as a connection host from Workbench? By the way, in the code above I've just noticed that you have "$shh_tunnel" and not "$ssh_tunnel". Is it a typo, or is that an error?

Comment: yeah, that's definitely a typo, sorry!  the MySQL Workbench connection info is in the first code block above, I copied it from there

Comment: Okay, edited answer. Normally you should use 127.0.0.1 if the SSH and MySQL server are the same. However, try using the remote MySQL IP address in the SSH2 connection string (I've explained why in the answer).

Comment: I've just updated my post with what I've just tried - not sure if I've used the correct IPs in the right place...

Comment: "$mysql_host" is *not* "localhost", is it? Because that's the only way I can figure you can get that message. The server sees the connection as coming from *localhost* (which it doesn't allow). I've tried running the same code myself, using my own IPs, and *it works*.

Comment: No, the IP address for $mysql_host is external and the same goes for $ssh_host too (although that's s different IP address). I think this is where it's all complicated, hence me getting rather confused on how to solve this! I do appreciate your help though!!!

Comment: If the error is really "access denied to user@LOCALHOST", and the server you connect to is NOT local, then it is a very large bug in the TCP/IP routines that make the Internet work. I have checked this with three hosts, and I can only state that it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the reason for your SSH-only constraint is, your question could have multiple answers. I'm going to go with this one because it's my exact user case: The MySQL service is bound to accept connections only from its own server or through a private IP and the app servers that use it are on different machines which are on the same network.

If that's the case, the simplest way to solve your problem and save you from the hassle of opening tunnels between servers is to either use the MySQL server's private IP in the connection string or set up the etc/host file on your app server with an alias to the MySQL server's private IP.

That way, you can use just the mysqli_connect string as you would do it normally

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're referring to but we have already added the IP for the remote server on where the code is run to be allowed access to the database server. The only IPs I've been given are those I'm trying to use...

Comment: What is the reason for needing to do this? Is the mysql user `$mysql_user` configured to only accept connections from localhost?

Comment: I don't know this to be honest, all I know is that we have a firewall manager that allows certain IPs to access the IPs on our servers (I'm not that technical unfortunately)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to connect python with mysql connector
First open your python prompt mainly use anaconda because it has all in built pakages first off all import mysql.connector then 
Connect to mysql like localhost username password database then enter the sql commands to insert delete search commands

Comment: Greetings, please find the `.` and the "Enter" button on your keyboard and use them ;-)  Your answer might be good, but it is difficult to read as it is now.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  However, I'm using PHP and my question is a little more complicated thank just connecting :)