# How to connect to remote MySQL via PHP+SSH?

Tags: php, ssh, pdo, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a MySql database via PHP. The database is running on a remote server, where I have access. But I'm unable to establish a connection.

I've already studied here a lot to find the reason, but for what reason ever it wont work.

In PHP I'm doing the following (as I also read in the forums):

```
shell_exec("sshpass -p SSHPASS ssh -L 33065:$dbhost:33060 SSHUSER@SSHHOST sleep 5");
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;port=33065", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

The remote database runs on port `33060` and the local port `33065` isn't used. The `sshpass` command is used to send the password to `ssh`.

I get a always `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` and the tunneled connection isn't established.

Is there something I do wrong or forgot to do?

Comment: Shouldn't you replace the `$dbhost`in the second line with `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`)? That's assuming you have the same setup as https://stackoverflow.com/q/52114738/7528944

Comment: `$dbhost` is a variable with a value of `127.0.0.1`